# WooCommerce protect 1 product field by password

Tags: woocommerce, field, hide

I am using WooCommerce for a clients website and have created an extra tab field (using YIKES extra tab plugin) and I would like it only to be visible when someone is a logged in user.

Currently the WooCommerce is set to catalog mode and will be for quite some time.

My clients wants to use the (soon to be hidden) new tab to be notes for his staff that he does not want the public to see

I have WooCommerce Membership plug-in but I think to restrict something there it would mean all viewers would need to register and I don't want that

so to summarize - I want a field in a Woo Commerce product that can only be viewed if a user is logged in

.... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem about working with Plugins is that it has his own "code" to do things. Sometimes the plugin overwrite templates, so it going to be difficult to modify the "core" of the Plug in to do that.

About your question.

> I want a field in a Woo Commerce product that can only be viewed if a
>   user is logged in

You can use the function `is_user_logged_in()` with an `If()` 
As an example. The code below display the text "IVA INCLUDED" if the user is logged in. The text is shown below the price in Product Page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_total_product_price');
function woocommerce_total_product_price() {
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    if(is_user_logged_in())
    {
    echo sprintf('<div> IVA Included </div>');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for that - but i wanted a field my client could edit (as he will be adding/updating the info to be displayed)